# Mac can't remove php 7.2

Tags: php, macos

Can't remove php from mac, tried everything on web
I tried to remove it via Terminal, and when i type **php -v** it returns : **command not found**, but when I try to install magento on the localhost It says **I still have php 7.2 installed**, tried to remove with homebrew, terminal, no use
Please help me to remove it, or at least downgrade to php 7.0

Comment: Why downgrade to a non-supported and EOL version of PHP?

Comment: magento does not support php 7.2 only 7.0

Comment: The latest stable version is available on php 7.1, which is still supported https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: How did you installed php? Using brew or source?

Comment: brew, and I cant delete it with brew now

Comment: My bad yeah it supports php 7.1 but I have 7.2 and have no idea how to get rid of it!

Comment: Nope, mac has some restrictions, as I said I removed every file with php I could find, removed it in recovery mode with terminal, now when I type php -v - it says command not found.... but when I run "brew install php70" i get "php@7.0 7.0.30 is already installed and up-to-date" and still command not found when i type php -v LOL

Comment: maybe theres just mess in your $PATH

Comment: Eakethet - Thanks a lot, found a lot of mess there, I've reinstalled php and still nothing returns when I write php -v